# I keep getting an error on SetLayoutParams - cannot be referenced from a static context?

Tags: android-studio, android-imageview, android-context, layoutparams

**I have pasted the whole class below from android studio.   Im trying to create a gallery using image view and GridView.**

```
package com.example.sc.loginappexercise;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by sc on 16/03/2017.
 */

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public Context context;
    public int[] images = {
            R.drawable.gallery1, R.drawable.gallery2,
            R.drawable.gallery3, R.drawable.gallery4,
            R.drawable.gallery5, R.drawable.gallery6,
            R.drawable.gallery7, R.drawable.gallery8,
            R.drawable.gallery9, R.drawable.gallery10,


    };

    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return images [position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Below where it says setLayoutParams - it stays red and throws an error. cannot be referenced from a static context? **

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        ImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(240, 240));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `ImageView` to `imageView`. Here `ImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(240, 240));`

Comment: Thank You. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`ImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(240, 240));` **=>**  `imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(240, 240));`

**I => i**

That's all!